# Creating 2 Interfaces in php with the same method's name and implementing it on a derived class

Tags: php, class, interface, abstract

**I am creating 2 Interfaces in PHP with the same method's name and implementing it on a derived class. So, how can i get to know that which one of the Interface is getting used?**

```
<?php
    interface car{
        public function intro();
        public function carName():string;
    }
    interface car2{
        public function intro();
        public function carName():string;
    }
    class price{
        protected $volvo="$50000";
        protected $audi="$86000";
        protected $buggati="$960000";
        protected $tata="$7000";
    }
    class model extends price implements car,car2{
        public $name;
        public $price="None";
        function __construct($n){
            $this->name=$n;
        }
        public function intro(){
            print"Welcome to the ".$this->name."'s showroom.<br>";
        }
        public function carName():string{        
            if ($this->name=="Volvo"){
                $this->price=$this->volvo;
            }
            return $this->name."'s car starting price - ".$this->price;
        }
    }
    $ob=new model("Volvo");
    $ob->intro();
    echo $ob->carName()."<br>";    
?>
```

Comment: Why does it matter, exactly? This is quite suspicious, though, as it probably means you should have a common base interface instead of duplicating the contract. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Reflection::export(new ReflectionClass('model'));
```

**Complete information about the class and its features**

```
Class [ <user> class model extends price implements car, car2 ] {
  @@ C:\index.php 16-31

  - Constants [0] {
  }

  - Static properties [0] {
  }

  - Static methods [0] {
  }

  - Properties [6] {
    Property [ <default> public $name ]
    Property [ <default> public $price ]
    Property [ <default> protected $volvo ]
    Property [ <default> protected $audi ]
    Property [ <default> protected $buggati ]
    Property [ <default> protected $tata ]
  }

  - Methods [3] {
    Method [ <user, ctor> public method __construct ] {
      @@ C:\index.php 19 - 21

      - Parameters [1] {
        Parameter #0 [ <required> $n ]
      }
    }

    Method [ <user, prototype car2> public method intro ] {
      @@ C:\index.php 22 - 24
    }

    Method [ <user, prototype car2> public method carName ] {
      @@ C:\index.php 25 - 30

      - Parameters [0] {
      }
      - Return [ string ]
    }
  }
}
```